# AWS Wordpress Configuration for Apache & EC2 User Access

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have for some time been manually switching my www/html directory user ownership on my EC2 Instance between apache and EC2-user for some time to allow me switch between installing and updating wordpress plugins or using Coda 2 to upload and update files via FTP.

I have finally reached a point of frustration and am wondering what is the best way to set up my ownership settings on the server to cater for both users having access without having to constantly change the settings.

Here are the commands I use to switch between users:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
```

Can someone please advise the safest configurations to avoid constantly switching for the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your user to the same user group of apache.

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
```

then exit your account then change ownership that include ec2-user in the path

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
```

Comment: sounds sensible, I'm just curious if that might be a security risk if someone gained access to my FTP login, would it open up access to the entire servers file system? Thanks

Comment: I just added ec2-user to apache group , and my ec2-user lost write access via my text editor with ftp access when ownership was changed to apache. Confirmed it worked by changing back to ec2-user ownership. Is there an additional step such as a server reboot for these types of group changes? thanks again

Comment: not quite sure about your question.but you'll just granting your main account to be in the same group of apache and has no security threat (for me)... if the ftp security reason is your really concern you can allow only your IP address that can access the server via FTP.

Comment: once you add your ec2-user to the apache group you need to exit your ec2-user by typing exit then relog back and check if the ec2-user is in the apache group by typing groups. I'll update my post

Comment: I'm sad to say, I'm still having the same issue before any changes were made to user groups. I have double checked that apache owns the /var/www directory and it does. When I use your last step to assign "ec2-user:apache" this will allow my FTP access with write permissions but WordPress still can't copy files unless using "apache:apache" and this will restrict my FTP access. Hmmm, I wonder what's missing here?

Comment: might want to check the file permission here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: Nailed it, I think I must have been messing up the file & directory owners by switching between users constantly and it got in a pickle. Running the recursive chmod commands fixed everything. Some good reading here to go with the last link in comments. https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache-2s-user-www-data-in-var